# Are there still field moves?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I just caught an Abra with Teleport and wanted to go back to a Pokémon Center. I have my Pokémon selection screen open, but it doesn't seem like I can use Teleport outside of battle. Am I still able to do that, or has that feature been removed? I would imagine this applies to things like Sweet Scent and HMs like Surf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you will find [HMs in Sun and Moon](https://www.vg247.com/2016/11/18/pokemon-sun-moon-guide-where-to-find-all-100-tms/). *Surf*, *Fly* and *Waterfall* used to be HMs but now they should only be relegated to TMs.

In Sun and Moon there's a new feature [Poké Ride](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ride) that allows you to ride on certain Pokémon. Each Pokémon allows the player to use a special ability.

> **Lapras Paddle** allows the player to to surf across water. The player can also fish from Lapras's back.
>
> **Sharpedo Jet** allows the player to surf rapidly and smash through rocks in the water.

---

Regarding [Teleport](http://pokemondb.net/move/teleport#move-descr), the SunMoon description only states:

> Use it to flee from any wild Pokémon.

when in XY and ORAS it was:

> Use it to flee from any wild Pokémon. It can also warp to the last Pokémon Center visited.

so it seems that it doesn't work anymore.

The same for [Sweet Scent](http://pokemondb.net/move/sweet-scent#move-descr), its description only states

> A sweet scent that harshly lowers opposing Pokémon’s evasiveness.

without any reference about if it can be used outside of battle.

Comment: I wouldn't trust that IGN link. Hordes are not in SM, and it was last edited 11 days ago.

Comment: Do you realize your new source doesn't state it can be used outside of battle?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yes. I was still editing it.

Comment: I can confirm that in Sun/Moon _Sweet Scent_ does not have an option to be used outside of battle to attract hoards.